# Check what version of the app is being used

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, version-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display the current project version of my App to the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492351/how-to-display-the-current-project-version-of-my-app-to-the-user)

Is there a way to check the version number of my app?  Is it supplied somewhere once the app is in the App Store?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I believe this is included in your [info.plist](http://www.innerexception.com/2008/10/iphone-app-version-and-build-numbers.html) file, and can be retrieved with code like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];
```

Comment: Do you now how to extract exactly version from this `NSTaggedPointerString`? For me it is returning `Version 1.0`, not `1.0` which is expected

Comment: You should read the code, the code above is adding the "Version" String in the result.